# Moving element in a loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to move the parent of these boxes from right to left and i have set the animation in loop.

```css
@keyframes move {
  to {
    left: -200px;
  }
}
#container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  animation-name: move;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

as you can see above the animaiton move the div and come back to its place. What i want is it to keep moving to the left and once the elements out of the screen i want to it come back from the right side of the screen and goes to the left screen ...

I know that's not possible with CSS alone. How can i achieve this using css/JavaScript.

> Graphic illustration of what i want to acheive

[image]

I want as soon as start crossing the screen i want it to start comming back to the screen from the opposite direction.

Comment: Did you mean to make "ping-pong" effect or "wrap" effect?

Comment: Not exactly sure what are those.. What i need is that if a div moves out of screen then i want it come from the opposite side of the screen and repeat this process in a loop

Comment: I need more clear how you really want, ping-pong is used to play animation until is done and goes to backwards more like sine animation. Wraping  simply does repositions of this object to the opposite side of the window if it leaves the area.

Comment: I don't think you can achieve this effect even using JS (unless you clone the elements). Reason I say this is because, the `div`s cannot be split into two when they near the edges like in your image. So, the only way without cloning them is to let them leave the page completely and then re position them.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question correctly you're looking for something like the code snippet below. If that's the case you don't need javascript, css is enough.

If you want it to hide relative to window width, your boxes need to be fluid (percentage instead of fixed px). You can play with the values.

If you want fixed width you can create a fixed width wrapper and set that to overflow hidden

```css
/* Fluid */
@keyframes move-1 {
  to {
    left: -50%;
  }
}
@keyframes move-2 {
  to {
    left: -20%;
  }
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.box {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.box:nth-child(1) {
  animation-name: move-1;
  left: 100%;
}
.box:nth-child(2) {
  animation-name: move-2;
  left: 130%;
}



/* Fixed */
@keyframes move-3 {
  to {
    left: -440px;
  }
}
@keyframes move-4 {
  to {
    left: -220px;
  }
}
#container2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid lightgrey;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.box2 {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
.box2:nth-child(1) {
  animation-name: move-3;
  left: 220px;
}
.box2:nth-child(2) {
  animation-name: move-4;
  left: 440px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Fluid Container</h2>
<div id="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<h2>Fixed Container</h2>
<div id="container2">
  <div class="box2"></div>
  <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice Solution but it won't work for me. Because i have more than two div and all are dynamic. Second what i want is that div keep moving from right to left and as soon as the first div leaves the screen it start coming back from the other side of the screen

Comment: Is the number of the divs unknown then? If so you'll have to use a fixed width for the **.box** and then you'll have to set the width of the container with js multiplied by the elements including spacing. And then position and animate the objects using that width as a base. I guess I'll need more info to explain better. Hope it helps a bit though.

Comment: I have updated question with a graphic illustration that i'll help you understand i want to achieve.

Comment: I ve created a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/rainb0w/y631rjc7/
Is it something like this you mean?
You can always play with the numbers to achieve exactly what you need

Comment: Its appearing on the opposite side once it fully cross the screen on the other side. What i want is appear whatever width that div already crossed. appears on the other side like the above graphic illustration

Comment: Well as I said if you play with it a bit you will achieve what you want
https://jsfiddle.net/rainb0w/y631rjc7/1/
I've edited it but you can do it better as you know exactly you need